# Is there any reason for using an enum for boolean in c++ instead of the already present bool?

Tags: c++, enums, boolean

I've found some code that declares an enum like this: `enum boolean {FALSE,TRUE};`

Is there any reason for using this instead of the normal `true` and `false` already present in c++?

Comment: Maybe someone is used to using capitals? ^^

Comment: This is wrong. It should be `{ True, False, FileNotFound}`. See http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: Because the more different ways to represent Boolean values the better!  Proves the superiority of the language.

Comment: Are you sure that it was C++? I found such declares in C-Code or Code with  a "C-history".

Comment: it is c++, i know it's used in a "c way", but since it uses cin and cout there's no reason for not using a c++ feature (it already doesn't compile with gcc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main drawback in C++ to using `enum` as another user-defined boolean is that it doesn't allow automatic conversions from a conditional expression:

```
enum boolean { FALSE, TRUE };

int main()
{
    boolean b;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    b = ( i == j ); // error
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f5623d7c7c42189)

See also [this old GotW column](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/026.htm) by Herb Sutter on why C++ choose to add a builtin `bool` type.

Comment: This has a "nice" error message: *error: cannot convert 'bool' to 'boolean' in assignment* which adds to the confusion.

Comment: Yeah this is why I asked mainly, the code is full of `foo(bar) == FALSE` instead of `!foo(bar)`

Comment: I encountered this when compiling Tesseract-OCR library.. This enum was defined in the library and in all the dependencies (libJPEG, libTIFF, libGIF, etc..) god it was painful to go through all the code and remove it.. I had "boolean already defined here.. #insert line number here". 100x. So +1 from me for a nice answer.